# What is the legislation (if any) behind self-employment Data Recovery/Destruction?

Tags: data-recovery

I am a self-employed technical advisor of about 2 years, and have run into a dilemma: Legislation for Data Destruction and Recovery.

Throughout my career, I've been asked many questions regarding the matter, and have had to turn down some aspects of a job due to lack of knowledge. I am aware of the core statues of the Privacy, Personal Data and Computer Misuse Acts (as well as most associated), though I have never come across any for this.

My question is: What is the legislation for this, and are there any licenses required to practice this?

Comment: what jurisdiction?

Comment: there are many standards for this: have you read the NIST standard?

Comment: @schroeder United Kingdom

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to include this vital information.